xla_latency_hiding_scheduler_rerun causing Colab TPU runtime crash
For the life of me, I cannot run my training script on Google Colab Pro TPUv2 runtime. I've been upgrading, downgrading, uninstalling, reinstalling to try and get all my dependencies compatible, but there's a new issue every time and I'm just lost at this point.
I am trying to train a google-t5/t5-base
Using the wikitext-103-v1 dataset for general language processing
Environment:
TPUv2 runtime
Python 3.10.12
Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Virtual environment
When I run my script, the last output I see is:
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch_xla/init.py:202: UserWarning: tensorflow can conflict with torch-xla. Prefer tensorflow-cpu when using PyTorch/XLA. To silence this warning, pip uninstall -y tensorflow && pip install tensorflow-cpu. If you are in a notebook environment such as Colab or Kaggle, restart your notebook runtime afterwards.
warnings.warn(
And then my runtime crashes and restarts. The runtime logs show:
Aug 26, 2024, 3:26:40 PM    WARNING WARNING:root:kernel xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx restarted
Aug 26, 2024, 3:26:40 PM    INFO    KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5), keep random ports
Aug 26, 2024, 3:26:38 PM    WARNING ERROR: Unknown command line flag 'xla_latency_hiding_scheduler_rerun'
I was first running into the following issue:
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-5baa930b08e9> in <cell line: 2>()
      1 import torch
----> 2 import torch_xla.core.xla_model as xm
      3 from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM
      4 from datasets import load_dataset
      5 

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch_xla/__init__.py in <module>
     18   sys.setdlopenflags(flags)
     19 
---> 20 import _XLAC
     21 from ._internal import tpu
     22 from .version import __version__

ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/_XLAC.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: _ZN2at23SavedTensorDefaultHooks11set_tracingEb

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

After various adjustments to my torch and torch_xla versions and dependencies, I kept getting these errors:
ERROR: Ignored the following yanked versions: 0.1.6, 0.1.7, 0.1.8, 0.1.9, 0.2.0, 0.2.1, 0.2.2, 0.2.2.post2, 0.2.2.post3, 0.15.0
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torchvision==0.15.1+cu118 (from versions: 0.12.0, 0.13.0, 0.13.1, 0.14.0, 0.14.1, 0.15.1, 0.15.2, 0.16.0, 0.16.1, 0.16.2, 0.17.0, 0.17.1, 0.17.2, 0.18.0, 0.18.1, 0.19.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torchvision==0.15.1+cu118
After reading some discussions, I ran the following (not all at the same time):
!pip uninstall cloud-tpu-client -y
!pip insrch~=2.4.0 torch_xla[tpu]~=2.4.0 -f https://storage.googleapis.com/libtpu-releases/index.html
!pip3 install --pre torch torchvision --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/nightly/cpu
!pip install 'torch_xla[tpu] @ https://storage.googleapis.com/pytorch-xla-releases/wheels/tpuvm/torch_xla-2.5.0.dev-cp310-cp310-linux_x86_64.whl' -f https://storage.googleapis.com/libtpu-releases/index.html
!pip install torch~=2.4.0 torch_xla~=2.4.0 https://storage.googleapis.com/pytorch-xla-releases/wheels/cuda/12.1/torch_xla_cuda_plugin-2.4.0-py3-none-any.whl
!pip3 install datasets
Which led to my current configuration (!grep -E 'torch|torch_xla|numpy|scipy|protobuf|six'):
numpy                        1.26.4
protobuf                     3.20.3
scipy                        1.13.1
six                          1.16.0
torch                        2.4.0
torch-xla                    2.4.0
torch_xla_cuda_plugin        2.4.0
torchaudio                   2.4.0+cpu
torchvision                  0.19.0+cpu
So, I don't know what to do anymore. This is my current script, which is based on a discussion I read regarding this issue so that it should detect the processor type and adjust, but it's giving me the same issue I had before:
%env source t5_env/bin/activate

from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

import os
os.environ["HUGGINGFACE_TOKEN"] = "####" 
import torch
import torch_xla
import torch_xla.core.xla_model as xm
device = xm.xla_device()

from datasets import load_dataset
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM, TrainingArguments, Trainer

# Set environment variable to avoid potential tokenizers parallelism issues
os.environ['TOKENIZERS_PARALLELISM'] = 'false'

# Load tokenizer and model
model_name = "google/t5-base"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name, use_auth_token=os.environ["HUGGINGFACE_TOKEN"])
model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained(model_name, use_auth_token=os.environ["HUGGINGFACE_TOKEN"]).to(device)

# Load the dataset
dataset = load_dataset("wikitext", "wikitext-103-v1")

def preprocess_function(examples):
    inputs = examples['text']
    targets = examples['text']

    model_inputs = tokenizer(inputs, truncation=True, padding='max_length', return_tensors="pt")
    labels = tokenizer(targets, truncation=True, padding='max_length', return_tensors="pt")
    model_inputs['labels'] = labels['input_ids']
    return model_inputs

tokenized_datasets = dataset.map(preprocess_function, batched=True)
tokenized_datasets.save_to_disk("/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/t5base/tokenized_datasets")

# Define training arguments
training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir="/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/t5base/checkpoints",
    num_train_epochs=3,
    per_device_train_batch_size=8,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=8,
    save_steps=1000,  
    logging_steps=100,
    eval_steps=500,
    evaluation_strategy="steps",
    learning_rate=2e-5,
    weight_decay=0.01,
    fp16=True,
)

# Model and trainer
data_collator = DataCollatorForLanguageModeling(tokenizer=tokenizer, mlm=False) 

trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    data_collator=data_collator,
    train_dataset=tokenized_datasets["train"],
    eval_dataset=tokenized_datasets["validation"],
)

# Training loop
from tqdm.auto import tqdm
with tqdm(total=len(trainer.get_train_dataloader())) as pbar:
    try:
        trainer.train()
        trainer.save_model("/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/t5base/final_model")
        print("Model trained and saved!")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Training error: {e}")

I'm sure I'm overlooking something real simple, but I just can't seem to figure it out. Any help would be tremendously appreciated.
